# alter default database for integrated user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a "windows integrated authentication" user whose default database was deleted.
Now when trying to login, we get an error saying, login for the user failed.
I found a solution from Microsoft to use SQLCMD. However, I am unable to issue the alter login command for that user. The error message states that the login 'mylogin' does not exist or you do not have permissions.
Unfortunately, I don't have sa credentials on that server.
Is there another way to change the default database on login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to issue the `ALTER USER` command from an account with sufficient privileges, or specify the `Initial Catalog` in the connection string when connecting, from whatever client app is being used.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to change the default database on login?

No. Have you tried logging in to a specific database, not the default?

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

has all info about connection strings you ever need. You can set an "Initial Catalog" in the connection string. That is not "the default of the user" but it is the one to be used for THAT connection.

Sadly, if you do not have the rights to create a db or reconfigure the user, that is where it stops... need to do that on every login then. Retrieve the SA password.